# I need to check whether my array input is an integer or an alpha but my program keeps one looping

Tags: c

Following is the main function 
I need to check whether my array input is an integer or an alpha but my program keeps on looping

```
int main (void) {
    int i; 
    float arr[3]; 
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){ 
        printf("Enter the weight of the cabin %d:\t", i+1); 
        scanf("%f", &arr[i]); 
        if(isdigit(arr[i])){
            *im not sure about this part*\
            printf("Cabin %d is %.2f\n", i+1, arr[i]);
        }else{ 
            printf("Error! Please enter the weight of the cabin %d again:\t", i+1); 
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]); 
            printf("Cabin %d is %.2f\n", i+1, arr[i]); 
        } 
        if(i==2){ 
            i=0-1; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I am hoping that my output will be like :

Enter the weight of the cabin: r
Error! Please enter the weight of the cabin again:

However, I get this.
Enter the weight of the cabin: r
It loops like crazy and i cannot see whats appearing on the screen

Comment: This code is completely unreadable. If not indentation, at the least consider writing statements on separate lines. There is no way one can make any sense out of this.

Comment: If a fellow of yours asked you help them make sense of their code, and presented you with a mess such as this, would you be inclined to help? What if it was a complete stranger, like you are to us?

Comment: I'm sure the program samples of your C textbook are not formatted like this.

Comment: ah for that im sorry because i have no idea how this site actually works. give me a while and i will change it again

Comment: Please show your input as well as actual and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that the `scanf` fails, and without removing the alphabetical text from `stdin`. That means that the next `scanf` also fails, and so on.

You need to check the return value of `scanf` and if you fail to scan a number, you need to remove the non-numeric input from `stdin`. I would recommend using `fgets` to remove one entire line of input from `stdin` when you get a failure from `scanf`.

```
    while (1 != scanf("%f", &arr[i])) {
        // Scan failed! Remove input line with non-numeric input
        char tmp[100];
        fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin);
        printf("Not a number! Enter the weight of the cabin %d:\t", i);
        fflush(stdout); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit()` can be used to check for a single character. What you are passing to it is a float (which might be completely malformed). 
What you need to do is read the input as a string and check for each character till you encounter a '\0'.

Besides that, the reason your program keeps looping is

```
if(i==2){ 
    i=0-1; // i = -1;
}
```

You are never letting i go above 2 for the loop to stop.